# Excel VBA: How change cell alignment from a public function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How to write a UDF or Public Function that also changes the layout of the cell from where it is called? More specific: enable the WrapText, as the result of my function generates a lot of text.

I tried a lot of variations around  `Application.Caller, .Address, ...`  to make `.WrapText = True` .
But without luck.

Example:

```
Public Function (X as integer, Y as integer) as integer
    Dim Z as integer
    Z = X + Y

    - insert suggested code to make .WrapText from cell true -

End Function
```

Comment: Functions called from the worksheet(UDF) cannot in themselves change the format of any cell including itself.

Comment: here is a workaround that might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet